# How to append the ajax result to the target div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using the following ajax code to get the result form another one php, now I need to append the result to the appropriate div(preview) id

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    target: '#preview'
}).submit();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery Form Plugin,  Use like this..data is the data which you are sending from php file.

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            clearForm: 'true',
            success: function(data){
            if(data != '')
            {
                $("#preview" ).append(data);
            }
            }
        }).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `success` callback function and don't specify the `target` option.

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    success: function(d,s,x){
       $("#preview").append(d);
    }
}).submit();
```

The problem is that the `target` option is used to "replace" the target (or contents of the target) along with the `replaceTarget` option. But since what you need to "append" instead of "replace", you should avoid the whole `target`/ `replaceTarget` mechanism